# What to do after setting environment variable for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-vision, vision-api

i have set environment variable for google credentials but i don't know what is the next step. Please help me to solve this error

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:119)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:127)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredentials.java:100)
at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:53)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:134)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.create(GrpcImageAnnotatorStub.java:61)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.stub.ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.createStub(ImageAnnotatorStubSettings.java:93)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.<init>(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:131)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:112)
at com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.create(ImageAnnotatorClient.java:103)
at com.example.vision.QuickstartSample.main(QuickstartSample.java:42)
```

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHUip.jpg)

Comment: Refer this document for the [next step](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication). From your post, I understand you are trying to setup authentication for the server and trying to provide credentials to your app. You can follow steps described in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application). Alternatively, you can create a service account and provide credentials manually as explained in the next paragraphs on the same page. Let me know this helps?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion..!  - @DSaini
I have tried this option for set the environment variable.

set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=PathToYourJsonFile

Comment: Can you confirm if that resolved your query? If yes, I will update the answer.